# ¿Mejor manera para hacer un continue para las próximas iteraciones?

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles, iteradores

Quiero que en un bucle `for i in range(10)`, si se cumple la condición `i == 2`, entonces se ignoren las próximas 2 iteraciones; y, si no se cumplen, entonces imprima i:

```
saltando=False
for i in range(10):
    if i == 2:
        saltando=True
        continue
    if saltando:
        saltando=False
        continue
    else:
        print(i)
```

Output:

```
0
1
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Ese código solo valdría para saltar la próxima iteración.
Si en vez de saltar 2 iteraciones tuviera que saltar más, podría añadir una condición y quitar `saltando`:

```
if 1 < i < 4:
```

pero siento que esta no es la mejor manera cuando en vez de un `for i in range` tengo un `for i in lista`.

```
lista=[0,1,2,0,2,4, 9]
for i in lista[:-2]:
    if i==1:
        continue*3 # Expresión inventada
    else:
        print(i) # 0, 2, 4, 9
```

¿Cuál sería la mejor manera en ese caso de saltar las próximas iteraciones?

Comment: Creo que yo usuaría un `filter`. En cuanto pueda publico una respuesta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solución sería crear un iterador para usar en el bucle. El iterador almacena internamente en su estado la posición siguiente a iterar. Cuando se cumpla la condición, basta avanzar el iterador las dos posiciones o más que quieras.

Dicho en código:

```py
it = iter(range(10))
for i in it:
    if i == 2:
        # ignoramos éste y el siguiente valor
        next(it, None)
        continue
    print(i)
```

En el caso genérico, se pueden usar las funciones del módulo [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html). En la documentación hay algunas recetas que pueden ser de mucha ayuda. Entre las recetas hay definida la función `consume` para avanzar `n` posiciones en un iterador.

Por ejemplo, para avanzar 3 posiciones:

```py
from itertools import islice

n= 3

it = iter(range(10))
for i in it:
    if i == 2:
        next(islice(it, n, n), None)
        continue
    print(i)
```

Pero lo más sofisticado puede ser encadenar iteradores.

Podemos trocear el iterador `it` en una primera parte, hasta que se encuentre un determinado valor, y una segunda parte, con los elementos ignorados:

```py
from itertools import chain, islice, takewhile

it = iter(range(10))
it2 = chain(takewhile(lambda x: x != 2, it), islice(it, 2, None))

for i in it2:
    print(i)
```

Con `takewhile` obtenemos elementos del iterador hasta cumplirse la condición.

Con `islice` nos quedamos con los elementos a partir de una posición.

Con `chain` encadenamos los dos iteradores.

Answer (score 2):

Una opción es usar un [iterador](https://docs.python.org/es/3/glossary.html#term-iterator).
Desde dentro del bucle podemos avanzar la posición en la que estamos con el método [`next`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#next).

Una lista es un [iterable](https://docs.python.org/es/3/glossary.html#term-iterable).
Con el método [`iter`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/functions.html#iter) obtendremos un iterador a partir del iterable.
El iterador puedo usarlo en un bucle `for` de la misma manera que usaría el iterable.

```py
lista = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 4, 9]
iter_lista = iter(lista)
for i in iter_lista:
    if i == 1:
        # Si he encontrado un 1, avanzo dos posiciones
        for _ in range(2): next(iter_lista, None)
        # Continúo la iteración para no imprimir el elemento actual
        continue
    
    print(i)
# 0 2 4 9
```

Fíjate que en el segundo argumento de `next` he escrito el valor default `None`.
Si no tuviera valor default, y hubiera un 1 en la última posición de la lista, lanzaría un error [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration).
Este error me indica que no puedo seguir avanzando en el iterador.

---

Si opinas que son demasiadas líneas y que ensucian tu bucle, puedes esconder esto en una [función generadora](https://docs.python.org/es/3/glossary.html#term-generator):

```py
def filtrar_lista(lista):
    iter_lista = iter(lista)
    for i in iter_lista:
        if i == 1:
            for _ in range(2): next(iter_lista, None)
        else:
            yield i
    
lista = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 4, 9]
for i in filtrar_lista(lista):
    print(i)
```